# No valid "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options

Tags: error-handling, blockchain, web3js, metamask

I am using metamask extension. whenever I am trying to add any data to the rinkeby test network, it is showing this error:

> No valid "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options

I have already logged in to metamask.

It should show a metamask warning box for a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

As the error specifies that no particular account address is passing, most probably it is related to MetaMask.

In the **newer version of MetaMask**, we have to **turn off the privacy mode** or we have to include this code i.e. `ethereum.enable()`